# Импорт пользователей в Outlook Web App

Tags: windows, windows-server, outlook, exchange

Есть CSV файл с пользователями, как импортировать их в outlook web app?
Работал только с LAMP, поэтому слабо представляю как все устроено у microsoft. Пока что я поставил Win Server 2012 и на него Exchange Server 2013.
Я не прошу писать статьи огромные, дайте просто наводки, где копать и что учить)

Comment: Уточните, Вы пользователей у себя на сервере хранить собираетесь и почтовик своими силами делать будете (Exchange Server) или собираетесь использовать Office365 (Exchange Online)?

Comment: Я уже сделал импорт. Генерирую CSV файл c адресами и добавляю их с помощью команды csv-import (exchange powershell) в цикле.

Comment: Тогда сделайте ответ на свой же вопрос и пометьте его "как ответ" (галочка), иначе Ваш вопрос будет вечно висеть без ответа.